# How do I group multiple numeric variables in a mixed model with lmer?

Tags: r, lme4

Let's say I have three numeric variables a1, a2, a3.  Based on domain knowledge, I'd like for the three coefficients to come from a normal distribution to achieve the clustering and shrinkage that mixed models accomplish.

Same goes for b1, b2, b3.

This is not a typical application for mixed models, because it's usually categorical variables that are treated as random effects.  That being said, is there a way to create this model with `lmer`?  Many thanks.

```
library(lme4)
library(tidyverse)

n <- 200
df <- tibble(
  a1 = runif(n),
  a2 = runif(n),
  a3 = runif(n),
  b1 = runif(n, max = 10),
  b2 = runif(n, max = 10),
  b3 = runif(n, max = 10),
  y = 5 * a1 + 5 * a2 + 5 * a3 + b1 + b2 + b3 + 30 * runif(n)
)
df

# This is my initial attempt (unsuccessful)
model <- lmer(
  y ~ (||a1 + a2 + a3) + (||b1 + b2 + b3),
  data = df
)
```

Comment: This is tricky, I think you're going to need to adapt a multi-membership model. Will get back to this if I have a chance.

Comment: I've been reading the documentation thoroughly, but still haven't figured out how to do this with lme4 or nlme.